# write multiple strings to a file and add a new line

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm building a basic app that you choose from a spinner, select a color and click save. If the color you're looking for isn't in the spinner, you press a button and you can type it in to the EditText.
I'm trying to make it so I can write both the chosen spinner/edittext color and the date inside of the "colors.txt" file. at the moment, there are no errors but when i launch the app on my android it instantly crashes.

**Colorchooser.java**

```
package com.example.scalendar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Colorchooser extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_colorchooser);
    }


    public void writetoFile(String str) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("colors.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write("colorstring , datestring");
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.colorchooser, menu);
        return true;
    }  
}`
```

And here is my Strings.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">SCalendar</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="color_prompt">What was todays color?</string>
    <string name="SaveButtonText">Save To Calendar</string>
    <string name="textfieldhint">Enter color</string>
    <string name="otherbuttontext">Color not listed</string>
    <string name="othercolorexplanationtext">Dont see the color here? Click the button below and type it yourself.</string>


    <string-array name="color_arrays">
        <item>Select a color:</item>
        <item>Purple</item>
        <item>Orange</item>
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Pink</item>
        <item>Brown</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>
        <item>Black</item>
        <item>White</item>
    </string-array>

            <string name="colorstring">
                colorSpinner = findViewById(R.id.colorSpinner)
                colorSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
            </string>

            <string name="datestring"> 
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");
            Date now = new Date();
            String fileName = formatter.format(now).toString();
            </string>


</resources>`
```

And here's my Mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="Colorchooser" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/colorSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:entries="@array/color_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/color_prompt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/othercolorexplaination"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/colorSpinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/colorSpinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/othercolorexplanationtext"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSave"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/othercolorexplaination"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:onClick="writetoFile(String getcolor)"
    android:text="@string/SaveButtonText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/othercolor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ButtonSave"
    android:layout_below="@+id/otherbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="@string/textfieldhint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/otherbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/othercolorexplaination"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:onClick="othercolor.focusableInTouchMode(true)"
    android:text="@string/otherbuttontext" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Please post your Logcat, if the app is crashing.

Comment: Please read the logcat before posting it. And if you can't understand it, search for similar problems. If that doesn't help, come back here.

Comment: I honest to god have no idea how to use log cat. I downloaded alogcat on my galaxy s3 and it's not showing me anything related to the app, even when I launch it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some major misunderstandings on the relation between Java strings vs string variables, and string variables vs string resources:

1. This:

   ```
    outputStreamWriter.write("colorstring , datestring");
   ```

   Will always write "colorstring, datestring" to your file, so the file will look like:

   ```
   colorstring, datestring
   colorstring, datestring
   colorstring, datestring
   ```
2. You cannot expect Java code in your string resources to be executed:

   ```
   <string name="colorstring">
           colorSpinner = findViewById(R.id.colorSpinner)
           colorSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
   </string>
   ```

   Strings in your resources are `Constants`. There is no way to change them at run time.

Comment: I see. How would I go about adding the date and spinner/EditText field data to the colors.txt file?